# Create entity class from existing class using T4 templating

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, t4

I need to easily create/automate some boilerplate code from a simple class in C#/.NET. I have found the T4 templating engine, but I am hoping someone can perhaps give some guidence on how best to implement and if I am on the right track.

I have classes that all look very similar to this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BarryAPI.Api
{
    public partial class Client
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int OrganId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; } = null!;
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public string? Phone { get; set; }
        public string? Mobile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I am trying to (mostly) automate the creation of a matched class that looks like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Barry.Domain.Entities.Client.Email;
using Barry.Domain.Entities.Organisation;
using Barry.Infrastructure;

namespace Barry.Domain.Entities.Client;

[Table("Client")]
public class ClientEntity : Entity, IMapFrom<ClientDto>
{
    public const int TitleMaxLength = 50;
    public const int FirstNameMaxLength = 100;
    public const int LastNameMaxLength = 100;
    public const int GenderMaxLength = 20;
    public const int PhoneMaxLength = 20;
    public const int MobileMaxLength = 60;


#nullable disable
    public ClientEntity()
    {
    }
#nullable restore

    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; } = null!;
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string? Phone { get; set; }
    public string? Mobile { get; set; }
}
```

I understand I cannot make all the logic decisions in the template (Like MaxLength etc), but I am hoping to automate the bulk of it as there as many classes that need to be converted into entity models.

I have looked into T4, but I am struggling to know if this is the correct choice. Can anyone please shed a little light on this problem and if I am headed down the right path trying to solve it with T4?
I've been tasked with writing something up to semi-automate this process (mostly just to automate the typing/copy/paste by hand) and I am not sure if a simple console app to read the file and output what's required would be more efficient? Would it?

If you think T4 is the go, pointing towards a similar case tutorial/docs that you know of would be a huge help.

Thank you.

Comment: Why generate another almost identical class? Is there a real need or are you trying to follow some kind of "best practice" ? EF Core doesn't need base classes or mappings. AutoMapper doesn't need base classes or interfaces either. That's the whole point of AutoMapper - to map between classed using conventions. The default constructor isn't needed, unless you also have another constructor

Comment: I think the [CodeDom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/using-the-codedom) might also give some answers

Comment: @JochemVanHespen T4 templates are used because working with the CodeDOM is far too complicated. And T4 itself was replaced by source generators

Comment: What does `Entity` do? Why not make it generic, or an interface? Assuming you really need `ClientEntity`, since it's a `Client` it's better to inherit from `Client`. Back when ORMs were in their infancy and base classes were really needed, an `Entity<T>:T` class was used as the base. With NHibernate and EF though, the code and properties that used to live in `Entity<T>` is now part of the ORM's conventions, eg ID properties, value generators etc. This makes it a *lot easier* to use classes and ORMs, because it avoids spilling ORM details into the `Client`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've had great experiences with the CodeDOM though, once you get the hand on the classes in it is actually pretty easy to generate some code. Maybe I dont understand T4 good enough, but examining the problem i would look at the CodeDom as well.

Comment: Even the Max constants look weird - for one, they aren't constants. They'll change when the database column or logic changes, breaking any code that referenced them. A constant is meant to never change. The compiler is free to embed constant values into callers and never look them up unless the caller itself is rebuilt. EF scaffolding code will convert column sizes into data annotation attributes or fluent API restrictions

Comment: @JochemVanHespen CodeDOM existed before T4. Writing a single expression in CodeDOM takes 20 or more lines. Making even a simple change would modify a *lot* of lines. That's why it's used so little, and why it was replaced by source generators.

Comment: @JochemVanHespen especially for this case, CodeDOM was never used. People used T4 code generators extensively to scaffold DTOs from database definitions. PS: Another reason CodeDOM wasn't used is that it's too limited and can't produce the same code one would write by hand

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos we are getting a bit off topic here. But aint it just the matter of writing some basic function which abstract a way some plumbing you gotta do with the CodeDOM?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes i know, it is used by EF as well. Im not against the T4 approach just pointing out the at least for me the CodeDOM was a bit easier to get into :D

Answer (score 0):

T4 templates and execution subsystem not designed to EDIT any of existing files - T4 used to generate whole file and replace existing one.

You can put any logic you want in T4-template or in side DLL's used by the template. Any, including any kind of parsing existed C#/VB/F#&etc files. Just pay attention to complexity of T4-template - it difficult to support when pieces of text mixed with complex code.